# emacs python-mode: designate which python shell to send commands to

Tags: emacs, python-mode

A follow up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281762/emacs-python-mode-python-ipython-multiple-instances-of-python-shell) - if I have two python shells running in emacs, how can I designate which shell commands from each python script buffer is sent to? I suspect it has something to do with `python-buffer` and `python-set-proc` but setting these variables to the name of the shell is apparently not the solution.

**Edit**: actually since I am using `python-mode` rather than loveshack python, it probably does not have to do with `python-buffer` and `python-set-proc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any Python buffer, you can use the variable `py-which-bufname` to control which Python shell your code gets sent to when executing it. The variable is buffer-local, so in order to set it to a custom value you'll need to change it from within the buffer by pressing `M-:` and entering the following

```
(setq py-which-bufname "My-Custom-Bufname")
```

This also makes it easy to quickly create **new** process buffers: If you set `py-which-bufname` to a name for which there is no corresponding process buffer, you can just issue `C-c !` to quickly create one.

HTH

Comment: Case closed! Thanks - this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: This variable does not seem to exist anymore. As this question arrived first on my search engine, here is the modern way. The variable is now named `python-shell-buffer-name`. By using `add-file-variable`, you can define a buffer-specific value to this variable with a string, like `"TOTO"`. It will then create a buffer named `*TOTO*` with the python shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a new value to `python-buffer`.

```
(defun my-python-set-proc (buffer-name)
  (interactive "B")
  (setf python-buffer (get-buffer buffer-name))
  (python-set-proc))
```

And then <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>`my-python-set-proc`<kbd>RET</kbd>`*Python*`<kbd>RET</kbd>,
or <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>`my-python-set-proc`<kbd>RET</kbd>`*Python*<2>`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks - it was my mistake that I suggested `python-buffer` and `python-set-proc` as they appear to be relevant variables for loveshack python rather than `python-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

py-shell-name sets the default, which might be overwritten by command

Should the buffer code contain a shebang specifying pythonVERSION , than this takes precedence over default setting.

You may enforce executing buffer through specific pythonVERSION by calling a command of class py-execute-buffer-pythonVERSION

See menu PyExec, entry Execute buffer ...